# 2 Questions about autoencoder in h2o

Tags: python, h2o, autoencoder

Can anyone tell me which kind of auto encoder (sparse, denoising etc.) h2o implements by design or depends this only by the used options?

Second Quesition:
Whats the difference between H2ODeepLearningEstimator() with autoencoder enabled and H2OAutoEncoderEstimator?

Thanks in advance.